# How to add local conda environment to Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I'm using conda version 4.3.29 on Ubuntu and I'm trying to add a local conda environment to Pycharm. When I try to add the environment to Pycharm under the Project Interpreters I don't see a python binary under the path anaconda3/envs/.  How do I change the interpreter to use the environment if there isn't a binary to select under that path?

Comment: I have the same question. Will post if I find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm preferences -> Project: [your project] -> Project Interpreter

Click the settings cog to the right of the project interpreter field. From there you can `Add Local` and use the explorer to find your `virtualenv`. In my case I had mine stored at `/Users/my_stuff/.virtualenvs/my_virtualenv`

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv though.